# Can't toggle display of table rows in IE with getElementsByName()

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I want to show and hide rows of a table based on the value of a select box and this works in Firefox but not IE:

```
<select onChange="javascript: toggle(this.value);">
 <option value="cat0">category 0</option>
 <option value="cat1">category 1</option>
</select>

<table>
<tr name="cat0">
  <td>some stuff v</td>
  <td>some stuff v</td>
</tr>
<tr name="cat0">
  <td>some stuff d</td>
  <td>some stuff d</td>
</tr>
<tr name="cat1">
  <td>some stuff a</td>
  <td>some stuff a</td>
</tr>
<tr name="cat1">
  <td>some stuff b</td>
  <td>some stuff b</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(category)
{
    // turn everything off
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var cat = document.getElementsByName('cat' + i);
        for (var j = 0; j < cat.length; j++)
            cat[j].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // turn on category chosen
    var cat = document.getElementsByName(category);
    for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++)
        cat[i].style.display = '';
}
// start by showing cat0
toggle('cat0');
</script>
```

Comment: `tr` elements don't have a name attribute. That's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE doesn't let you access table rows using the `document.getElementsByName` method.  If you use ID's instead of name's it will work.  See this page for code that does just what you are looking for: http://www.toolazy.me.uk/template.php?content=getelementsbyname.xml

Comment: Huh, you learn something new every day, but I think setting the `display` property to `table-row` will also be needed.

Comment: @SeattleLeonard `table-row` is not supported by IE - http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

With table rows in your second for loop you need to set the display property to `table-row`

Answer (score 0):

There is actualy an IE bug You can use! Simply set for each element both name and id (both must have same value!).
For example:
`<tr name="cat0" id="cat0">`
Now `getElementsByName` will work in IE too.

ps. I know this is old question, but i was trying to solve this problem 5min ago. So it might help someone :p